# can we set activity type in c#

Tags: c#, discord-rpc

I want to change the "Playing a game" to "Listening music" or some other stuff, I tried to google it but didnt got any results
so if yall could help it would be great thank you

```
client = new DiscordRpcClient("961726309740970065");

        client.Logger = new ConsoleLogger() { Level = LogLevel.Warning };

        client.Initialize();

        client.SetPresence(new RichPresence()
        {
            Details = "Using the greatest exploit available in the whole galaxy",
            Timestamps = Timestamps.Now,
            State = "Slobby ",
            Assets = new Assets()
            {
                LargeImageText = "Download the god of exploits(Slobby Xploits)",
                LargeImageKey = "slxp"
            },
            Buttons = new DiscordRPC.Button[]
            {
                new DiscordRPC.Button() { Label = "Download Slobby Xploits", Url = "https://direct-link.net/414115/gateway-to-heaven" },
                new DiscordRPC.Button() { Label = "Join our Discord", Url = "https://discord.gg/WaTuKge4kC" }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is a old question now, but i will post this here for future people. Discord's Rich Presence does not let you set the activity type. Whatever you send will just be ignored.

Spotify have special edge-case written into discord itself to allow them to set it to Listening To.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you've already fixed that, but it's actually very easy to do:

```
Type = ActivityType.Playing // Changes the activity to 'Listening to music'
```

The enum contains all activity types for the discord rich presence.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: My Rich Presence library literally does not support this. Type does not exist.